# instantiation of template function for different types

Tags: c++, templates

I wanna instantiatizate template function for given types.

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T arg1, float arg2, T * arg3) { ... }
...
template void foo<int>(int arg1, float arg2, int * arg3);
template void foo<float>(float arg1, float arg2, float * arg3);
...
```

Is there a way to do it more automatically ? So that, for instance, I don't need to make changes for each type every time I change argument list.

@edit

the best I could come up with

```
#define RUN_MACRO( X ) \
X( float ) \
X( int )

#define INSTANTIATE(type) template void Foo<type>(type, float, type* );
RUN_MACRO( INSTANTIATE )
```

Comment: if you put it in header, no (explicit) instantiation is needed

Comment: Why do you want to do that ?

Comment: why do you think you would need to make changes everytime the argument list changes?

Comment: @Jarod42 There are valid (and very obvious) reasons for doing what he wants to do. This is one way of _not_ having the full template code in the header - as long as you know beforehand which types the template will be needed with.

Comment: @user463035818 He wants to instantiate, not specialize.

Comment: I wanna put it in .cpp file because of compilation times for large template based project.

Comment: @Praetorian Because the functions have identical code, they just operate on different types?

Comment: @MaxLanghof Never mind, I somehow read this as specializing for different types

Comment: I'd just use a macro. `#define INSTANTIATE(type) template void foo<type>(type arg1, float arg2, type * arg3)`

Comment: @tkausl I had the same idea but I would have to write new macro for every function. I just wanted to know if there is some more generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might turns your overload into functor

```
template <typename T>
struct foo_impl
{
    void operator ()(T, float, T*) const;
};
```

Then in cpp file you can instantiate them

```
template <typename T>
void foo_impl<T>::operator ()(T arg1, float arg2, T* arg3) const
{
    // Your code
}

// instantiations where you provide only T
template struct foo_impl<int>;
template struct foo_impl<float>;
```

So to have "same" interface, you might create instance which handle overload:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
struct foo_overload : foo_impl<Ts>...
{
    using foo_impl<Ts>::operator()...; // C++17
};

constexpr static foo_overload<int, float> foo;
```

Before C++17, you have to use recursion for the variadic using :/

```
template <typename ... Ts>
struct foo_overload;

template <typename T>
struct foo_overload<T> : foo_impl<T>
{
    using foo_impl<T>::operator();
};

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct foo_overload<T, Ts...> : foo_impl<T>, foo_overload<Ts...>
{
    using foo_impl<T>::operator();
    using foo_overload<Ts...>::operator();
};
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/HJH2-1Raz)

But really I would keep header (which is your interface) simple:

```
void foo(int arg1, float arg2, int* arg3);
void foo(float arg1, float arg2, float* arg3);
```

and in cpp:

```
template <typename T>
void foo_impl(T arg1, float arg2, T* arg3) { ... }

void foo(int arg1, float arg2, int* arg3) { foo_impl(arg1, arg2, arg3); }
void foo(float arg1, float arg2, float* arg3) { foo_impl(arg1, arg2, arg3);}
```